# Bad behavior from Jetpack compose HorizontalPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with the HorizontalPager of the new framework Jetpack Compose.  When I associate the HorizontalPager with a TabRow, everything works fine until I reach the last element of my TabRow (Title3) (by clicking the tab row or swipping till the last page). When I am on the last page, if I swip for 1 nanometer to the left the pager switch from last page (Title3) to the previous one (Title2). It is not like other switch between pages, this one is instantaneous when others are continue. I hope I am enough clear to be understandable. Here is the code I use:

```
    val tabTitles = listOf("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = tabTitles.size)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column {
       TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions))
            }) {
            tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) } }
                )
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(4.dp)
            ) {
                when (page) {
                    0 -> // Create a list of card for each item
                    1 -> // Create a list of card for each item
                    2 -> // Create a list of card for each item
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me even if this is a new framework :/
I am open to other solution to implement this kind of pager without the HorizontalPager if the problem come from it and not from my code.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: It was a bug from google accompanist library on version 0.9.0, I solved my problem using the newest version (0.10.0).